# "defaults write ..." on .plist but does not work

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

Since Catalina (and probably in some other updates before) its not possible, to change certain MacOS configurations, i.e.:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState -bool true
```

I can see that the property is changed within the **~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist**, but the changes are not taken into account.

Any process, which needs to be restarted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to operate a Mac.  Those questions may be asked at the [appropriate forum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have the same Problem. Any solution yet?